# What's the difference between fight and battle when they are used as a verb?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I just cannot understand these two words. I have googled differences of these two words in italky, etc. And many people said "A fight is usually used for small scale things.""A battle is a large scale fight that's part of a war." But my teacher taught me the following ones are correct:

My grandfather **fought** in world war II.

Doctors are still **battling** to save the child's life.

I think war is very big scale thing.

Comment: We might just as well say 'Doctors are _fighting_ to save her life'. What you say of the nouns is correct, but _battle_ as a verb is usually used only in the metaphorical sense, not of actual combat. Macmillan defines it as _to try very hard to deal with a difficult situation_.

Comment: You conflate the nouns and the verbs in the above. Their distributions should be considered separately. // Note that there's no absolute rule. As with most of English, it takes years (I actually typo'd 'tears'!) to get close to a mastery. But I'd point out that the verb _battle_ is far more rarely used than the noun when talking about wars (and possibly in general). 'Dick and Dave were battling in the playground' is wry, tongue-in-cheek; 'were fighting' is the normal, unmarked way of putting this.

Comment: “*battle*” being associated with part of war might be in part due to the saying “I may have lost the battle, but you haven’t won the war!”

Answer (score 1):

Two points.

Firstly no matter how big the battles were in which your grandfather took part his individual contribution would have been on a personal scale.

Secondly the description of doctors 'battling' to save a child's life is a *metaphor*. They are not fighting like soldiers they are doing their very best, medically, to save the child. They aren't fighting against other people, they are working against the infection or other physical condition that threatens the child.

Answer (score 0):

Verbs:

“To battle” is pretty rare. It’s meaning is almost synonymous with fight (two dictionaries used fight in the definition, e.g. “to fight or struggle against”). It always seems to have a more dynamic and ongoing aspect - unrelenting and continuous, if not intense.

Nouns:

In military terms, a battle is usually seen as a single incident of engagement at a location. May be long, but is one engagement. There may be exceptions in a
military context, but those are from the non-military usage creeping into a military context (“The battle for control of the Pacific” may be military and could be used now, but is an example of what I’m saying.) I feel pretty confident that historically, a battle was always this one engagement at a location.

Even in non-military usage, battles have the feel of being, if not an engagement at a location, none the less a potential *subset* of a conflict between the parties. There is some notion of battles having a domain. You’re more likely to hear about a battle *for* something or a battle *over* something or *at* somewhere than you are to hear about the battle between parties generically. As if there is a theater whether it be topic or location or object of control (the battle for young minds)

A fight is much more general. Fights can sometimes just be between parties; battles are about things. Feuds are fights but are not battles. Fights can go on through time and space, but they don’t have to. That’s part of fight being a more general term. Battles are open, active conflict within a domain. Perhaps that’s why I mentioned ongoing, continual, and intense with respect to the verbs.

Even if I fry to get away from that aspect of a battle with context, as in

> The ongoing battle between Bob and Bill.

My mind at least is expecting “specifically the battle **over**” such n such.

If I had more time this would be shorter. Hopefully that helps some anyway. Great question. Gotta go.

Answer (score -1):

The words 'battle' and 'fight' are synonymous and equally interchangeable in your example sentences. Battle is derived from the Old French word 'bataille' which means *to fight*, whereas 'fight' has Proto-Germanic origins from 'fechten' which means *struggle with*.

References:

https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=battle

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fight

Comment: -1 for personal views. I’ll happily reverse my vote if you [edit] your answer to provide an authoritative reference to support your assertion, but I think you’ll find there’s a subtle difference in usage.

Comment: Deleted my personal viewpoint and provided authoritative reference. Entomologically there is no discernable difference between these two synonyms.

Comment: But arguments from etymology are almost always flawed. Usage changes and distributions become more idiosyncratic. 'The fight of the sexes' is not a fixed expression. More significantly, 'battle' is often not useable instead of transitive 'fight'; 'You have to learn to fight your own battles.' / 'Here, they fought the first skirmish of the campaign.' / 'Fight the good fight.' And with prepositions / particles: 'They fought off the besieging army.' / 'He fought in France.'

Comment: In the context in which she used it as a verb with her example sentences, they are perfectly synonymous. Of course, going by idiomatic expressions and phraseologies, there will be those respective idiosyncrasies. In her case, it is just a matter of taste. Essentially, the two words possess the same core meaning which is to contend against (someone/something).

Comment: Your ''The words 'battle' and 'fight' are synonymous and equally interchangeable considering their etymology'' is lacking a caveat. As does OP's title question. // You really think that "My grandfather battled in World War II" is something native speakers would consider natural?

Comment: Your answer provides an etymology for the two words but completely fails to explain why the two words "are synonymous and equally interchangeable". Even the etymological roots you provide show a divergence of meaning: "to fight" is not the same as "to struggle with". Your answer is simply **wrong**. Simple test: does any parent tell their children to "stop battling"? The words are *not* "equally interchangeable".

Comment: Edited it. In the example sentences provided, battle and fight are equally interchangeable. Happy now?